# How should I store isFetching/isLoading data in my redux store?

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

I am looking to create a generic way of storing isFetching for entities/data in redux. Currently I use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) and store all my entity data in an entities hash. For example

```
{
   people: { ... },
   orders: { ... }
}
```

I was thinking of [defining a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on each entity (i.e. people, orders ...) object to specify whether or not data is being fetched. The only problem with this is if you do something like Object.keys you will return a list of ids + isFetching in your array. To overcome this I want to set the property to not being enumerable.

My data is fairly complex, I don't just have 2 entities, I have just simplified for the example. I am looking for a solution that can survive in my codebase in the long term.

Is this a good solution? I didn't want to create a new object just to store meta data (although this is a potential solution). Is there a better or more common approach?

I know this is slightly opinionated, but the redux issue guidelines pointed me to stackoverflow ...

Note I am aware of compatibility issues with Object.defineProperty. This is an internal application and everyone is on the latest version of chrome.

**UPDATE**

Potential implementation in the redux store

```
let initialState = {
  entities: {
    customers: null,
    orders: null
  }
};

Object.defineProperty(initialState.entities.customers, 
  'isFetching',
  {
    value: false,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false
  });

Object.defineProperty(initialState.entities.orders, 
  'isFetching',
  {
    value: false,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false
  });


export default initialState;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think defining non-enumerable properties will make your code base harder to maintain, because the fact that a property is not enumerable, is hidden most of the time when debugging.

You could just follow the examples from `normalizr` and have meta data sit next to the `entities`. E.g.:

```
{
  customers: {
    entities: {/** contains your normalized customer list*/},
    isFetching: false
  },
  orders: {
    entities: {/** contains your normalized order list*/},
    isFetching: false
  }
}
```

This would also allow for further extension of meta data in the future.

Comment: Currently I have `entities.people` in my store. Are you suggesting moving people to the root level i.e. inverting the way I store my entities? It could potentially be better in the long run, but it was nice grouping my entities under one section.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. But my answer is more about the point that meta data (imho) should be stored as a sibling of a list. Besides that, flatten the state of the store is always good. `entities` might not be the best domain, because it could mean literally everything (isn't everything from a REST endpoint an entity?). *Edit: Updates my answer.*

Comment: Ye I am using the technique given in the redux documetnation. The fact that you have entities can't be escaped. I do want to group all my unique data together somehow. I then use selectors for more specific data - filtered data etc ... https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/reducers/index.js

Comment: I totally agree with trying to keep things flat, notice that in both scenarios yours and mine they are both the same depth.

Comment: True, but only if you use your `defineProperty` technique. Adding my proposal would add another level, because you would have `entities.customers.entities` :) ...which would be kinda bananas.

Comment: Ye mixing the 2 is not really an option. I would either have to move all my unique data entities to the root level and have a grouping with in that "entities" and have related data or do it the other way with defined properties.